# Data bind an ItemsControl in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I seem to have a simple data-binding problem, but can't figure out the right way to do it. There is a `TabControl` which defines two `DataTemplate`'s, one for the tab header and one for the tab content.

The content template contains an `ItemsControl`. The ItemsControl tries to bind to a dynamically created `ViewModel` (ConnectionInfoVM).

When I display the UI, the binding just fails, but there is no error-message in the output about it.

How do I have to set up the DataContext and the binding so the binding works and the DataBuffer is actually displayed? Any help greatly appreciated.

ConnectionsControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXXViewer.Views.ConnectionsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:XXXViewer.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid> 
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Name="TabDynamic" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}" />
                        <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnTabDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                            <Image Source="{DynamicResource DeleteImg}" Height="11" Width="11"></Image>
                        </Button>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabContent" DataType="viewModels:ConnectionInfoVM">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ScrollViewer Name="Scroller" Background="Black">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="This line gets printed" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                                <ItemsControl Name="ItemCtrl" ItemsSource="{Binding DataBuffer}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ConnectionsControl code behind:

```
namespace XXXViewer.Views
{
    public partial class ConnectionsControl : UserControl
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<TabItem> _tabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();

        public ConnectionsControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // bindings
            TabDynamic.ItemsSource = _tabItems;
            TabDynamic.DataContext = this;
        }

        // assume this gets called
        private void AddTabItem(ConnectionInfoVM ci)
        {
            DataTemplate headerTemplate = TabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;
            DataTemplate contentTemplate = TabDynamic.FindResource("TabContent") as DataTemplate;

            // create new tab item
            TabItem tab = new TabItem
            {
                Header = $"Tab {ci.ConnectionID}",
                Name = $"T{ci.ConnectionID}",
                HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate,
                ContentTemplate = contentTemplate,
                DataContext = ci
            };

            _tabItems.Insert(0, tab);

            // set the new tab as active tab
            TabDynamic.SelectedItem = tab;
        }
    }
}
```

ConnectionInfoVM:

```
namespace XXXViewer.ViewModels
{
    public class ConnectionInfoVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly ObservableQueue<string> _dataBuffer = new ObservableQueue<string>();
        public ObservableQueue<string> DataBuffer => _dataBuffer;
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the tab that gets created:
[resulting tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xbCX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the ContentTemplate but never the Content, so the ContentTemplate is never applied because it's applied only when there's Content set. Instead of `DataContext = ci` write `Content = ci`.

By the way the `DataContext = ci` was useless because the DataContext is already implicitely the object on which the DataTemplate is applied.

**Edit**

As you're using WPF, use and abuse of its core feature: bindings.

How I would have written your code (if I didn't use full MVVM compliant code):

Your XAML:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="0" Name="TabDynamic" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems, Mode=OneWay}" 
            SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}" />
                <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnTabDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource DeleteImg}" Height="11" Width="11"></Image>
                </Button>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:ConnectionInfoVM">
            <TabItem Header="{Binding ConnectionID, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Name="{Binding ConnectionID, Mode=OneWay}"
                     HeaderTemplate="{StaticResources TabHeader}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ScrollViewer Name="Scroller" Background="Black">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="This line gets printed" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                            <ItemsControl Name="ItemCtrl" ItemsSource="{Binding DataBuffer}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>

        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

You cs code become much simpler:

```
namespace XXXViewer.Views
{
    public partial class ConnectionsControl : UserControl
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<ConnectionInfoVM> _tabItems = new ObservableCollection<ConnectionInfoVM>();
        public ObservableCollection<ConnectionInfoVM> TabItems {get {return _tabItems;}}

        public ConnectionsControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // bindings
            //TabDynamic.ItemsSource = _tabItems;
            TabDynamic.DataContext = this;
        }

        // assume this gets called
        private void AddTabItem(ConnectionInfoVM ci)
        {
            TabItems.Add(ci);
        }
    }
}
```

I noted while re-reading your code that you were probably confused about binding in code-behind.

Your code `TabDynamic.ItemsSource = _tabItems;` is not a binding, it will only set it once.

Anyway, I suggest you read a bit about MVVM. The TabItems should be in a ViewModel class instead of being in code-behind.

Comment: It works now with your suggested change. So, if I understand this right, this is how it works: I do have to set the content of the item. Based on the content, a matching template will be choosen. The DataContext will then implicitly be the content which I set (as this is the object on which the DataTemplate was applied). Thank you for clearing this up for me.

Comment: @ptair edited my post to include more information and more "WPF" approach. By Binding the ItemsSource in the XAML you won't have to create any Control in behind. Indeed, the DataTemplate will be implicitely choosen based on the Content type IF you don't give the DataTemplate a Key.

Comment: @ptair edited multiple times the code, made mistakes. It should almost be working

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the cleaner approach. Another question though:
"Your code TabDynamic.ItemsSource = _tabItems; is not a binding, it will only set it once."
Is it not a binding, because _tabItems itself is not in a class implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Or is this assignment in the code-behind never a binding? As far as I understand it, the other binding I created "TabDynamic.ItemsSource = _tabItems;" is really a binding. About the MVVM, as soon as it works fine, I will get rid of the code-behind stuff, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: 1) you cannot bind to a variable, only to a public property, so a binding in code-behind to _tabItems wouldn't have worked. 2) An ObservableCollection already implement a notification interface (ICollectionChanged) so you don't need that, the ObservableCollection will automatically notify the UI (if bound to a Control). An assignement is never a binding, but you can create bindings in code-behind (new Binding... look on the internet how to do it).

Comment: For your last question, the "TabDynamic.ItemsSource = _tabItems;" is not a binding. It kind of behaves like one because you're using an ObservableCollection but if you create _tabItems later on the "binding" won't work anymore (if you add items to the new _tabItems).

Answer (score 0):

The Tabcontrol as per your coding does not contain in it's `DataContext` the viewmodel but the control; so we need to find a control or something else which holds the VM. It does not appear that the page holds the VM in its `DataContext` either.

I recommend that one route is to use the TabControl's `Tag` property to hold the VM such as specifying it in code behind as such:

```
TabDynamic.ItemsSource = _tabItems;
TabDynamic.DataContext = this;
TabDynamic.Tag = {Wherever you are keeping your VM at this time its not clear in your code example};
```

Then you can specify `Tag` from the template binding by specifying the TabControls' name as such:

```
 <ItemsControl Name="ItemCtrl" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Tag.DataBuffer, 
                                           ElementName=TabDynamic}">
```

Comment: I don't see why the TabControl's DataContext would be an issue. The TabItem is created with a specified DataContext which is the ConnectionInfoVM

Comment: @nkoniishvt As I mentioned this is just one route, Sure, if the TabItem' has the VM, that would work. Provide it as an answer. I didn't want to use relative source binding.

Comment: Additionally, there are several tabs and each one has its own ConnectionInfoVM as DataContext, so just setting the ConnectionInfoVM  once on the TabControl is not going to work